# Is returning an error code value from stored procedure good practice?

Tags: c#, sql-server

In our company, we're using four types of simple stored procedures (insert, update, delete, select); database group persist on a rule that every single stored procedure should contain "error code" in return value for update/delete/insert stored procedure types.

To illustrate:

```
-------------------    
--INSERT sp example
-------------------
 INSERT INTO dbo.SomeTable(..) VALUES(...)

 if @@error <> 0
   return -1
 return 0

-------------------
--UPDATE sp example
-------------------
declare
@errsql int
@updcount int

update dbo.SomeTable set foo = @bar

select @errsql = @@error, @updcount = @@rowcount
if @errSQL <> 0     
  return -1
if @updcount < 1 
  return -2
return 0    

-------------------
--DELETE sp example
-------------------
delete from dbo.SomeTable where ...

if @@error <> 0
  return -1
return 0
```

This rule dates back to ages when we're using old ASP/VB6.0; however for a long age our platform is pure .NET and error on SQL side (such as primary key violation/unique index violation/etc.) is transferred to application as .NET exception, so following this pattern seems like a cargo cult programming (I can see checking updates rows count can be useful in some scenarios, still that should be driven by application developers, not by database group  - in the end you have to check return code in the app to have any effect :).

So my question is - can you see any benefit in this practice, or is this classical cargo cult programming example ?

Comment: Interesting that the goal appears to be replacing a possibly useful error value with a constant. And no use of try/catch. Or other helpful output, e.g. number of rows deleted which you might like to be greater than zero in most cases. I prefer to use `RaIsError` to provide useful diagnostic information. (Shall we chip in to buy another vowel for Microsoft?)

Comment: Why don't you use `RAISERROR` ?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel - this is not about how to throw an exception from SQL to .NET, this is about rule "every single stored procedure other than select should return error code" and its validity

Comment: This is not error handling. It is more like error suppression. Your code returns a -1 for anything that went wrong. How do you debug this kind of thing when you don't have any information anywhere about what actually happened? For basic CRUD operations I prefer to use no error handling on the sql side and let the application properly handle exceptions which would be returned from sql when something goes wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using exceptions in the rest of your project, I'd say exceptions should be the way to go. Notice you have the `RAISEERROR` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178592.aspx) SQL clause so you can raise exceptions within those stored procedures.

I believe the severity must be over 16 on RAISEERROR for it to be raised as an exception (you may want to check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx). Exceptions should rise for any error that would work on a `TRY/CATCH` SQL block.